# Assigns has been extracted to a gem. Use gem 'rails-controller-testing'. Is there an alternative for the gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing some tests for a controller tasks, the index action, which has an instance variable @tasks with all the tasks (`Task.all`).

If I follow the official documentation:

```
RSpec.describe TeamsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns @teams" do
      team = Team.create
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:teams)).to eq([team])
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end
end
```

The `assigns` method is moved to the gem file 'rails-controller-testing'. 
I have two questions:

1 - How can I achieve the same as `expect(assigns(:teams)).to eq([team])`. I guess I am asking, how can I check if I have an instance variable in the index action with values `[team]`

2 - If this method was moved to the gem, I read in the Github issues, that the reason is: You shouldn't test it there, controller should just test response, cookies etc. But I am confuse, since in relish you can test the instance variable. Should I test it there or not? If not, where? In my views/index_spec.rb, testing if I have all the teams?

3 - Alternative: Since TeamsController is a normal class, should I create a spec in the spec/models/folder `spec/models/tasks_controller.rb` and there test if the method `index` has the instance variable @teams with the content that I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea is that instead of poking inside your controller and testing its internal variables is flawed you should instead test your controllers by testing the output.

In RSpec you can do this with request and feature specs.

```
# config/specs/features/teams_spec.html
RSpec.feature 'Teams' do
  scenario 'when a user views the teams' do
    Team.create(name: 'Team Rocket')
    visit '/teams'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Team Rocket'
  end
end 

# config/specs/requests/teams_spec.html
RSpec.describe 'Teams', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /teams.json' do
    it "includes the team" do
      team = Team.create(name: 'Team Rocket')
      get teams_path(format: :json) 
      expect(parsed_response.first['name']).to eq 'Team Rocket'
    end  
  end
  describe 'GET /teams' do
    it "includes the team" do
      team = Team.create(name: 'Team Rocket')
      get teams_path
      expect(page).to have_content 'Team Rocket'
    end  
  end
end
```

The key difference is that feature specs test the app from a user story POV by driving a browser simulator while request specs are lighter weight and you just test against the raw response.

> 1 - How can I achieve the same as expect(assigns(:teams)).to
> eq([team]). I guess I am asking, how can I check if I have an instance
> variable in the index action with values [team]

Either use the assigns gem for legacy compatiblity or test the rendered output.

> 2 - If this method was moved to the gem, I read in the Github issues,
> that the reason is: You shouldn't test it there, controller should
> just test response, cookies etc. But I am confuse, since in relish you
> can test the instance variable. Should I test it there or not? If not,
> where? In my views/index_spec.rb, testing if I have all the teams?

If by Relish you mean RSpec, then its been taking a while for RSpec-rails to catch up to the state-of-art in Rails testing. But the same still applies. The offical recommendation of the RSpec team is to not use assigns and faze out controller specs in favor of request specs. View specs are not really relevant here - they are used if you want to test complex views in isolation.

> 3 - Alternative: Since TeamsController is a normal class, should I
> create a spec in the spec/models/folder
> spec/models/tasks_controller.rb and there test if the method index has
> the instance variable @teams with the content that I want?

Just no. Controllers are not just normal classes. You can't just instantiate a controller with `MyController.new`, thats why controller tests have all that stubbing in place.